# How to add missing borders to FMX controls?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I'm currently designing an FMX app with C++Builder. For some reason, when the app is built and launched (it looks normal in the editor), the upper and left border of `TComboEdit`s are missing. Same for the right border of grids. This is quite unpleasant to the eye, how to change that?

Here is the design-time settings for one of the `TComboEdit`s:

```
object SearchLotComboEdit: TComboEdit
  Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
  TabOrder = 2
  ItemHeight = 19.000000000000000000
  ItemIndex = -1
  Position.X = 72.000000000000000000
  Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
  Size.Width = 361.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  OnChange = SearchLotComboEditChange
  OnTyping = SearchLotComboEditTyping
  OnKeyDown = SearchLotComboEditKeyDown
```

I added pictures of what it looks like:

[image: TComboEdit]

[image: TGrid]

Comment: Perhaps you can add a small picture that shows the problem. I just tried and there was no problem with the borders of a `TComboEdit`. Also show the `.fmx` file content. Are you using styles?

Comment: I added all the info you could need i guess... and i'm not using any styles (didn't even figure out how to use them)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I see what you mean. Are you perhaps using Windows 7 (or older). I ask because I don't see the problem on Windows 10 (as they went away from the 3D look. In your image, the `TComboEdit` left and top looks like they are the same gray color as the form, and therefore appears as missing. I guess its the same with the grid. I need to check some options, but confirm your OS version.

Comment: I'm on windows 10, and whether it's on a white background like this or a more dark one, the border appears as missing the same way, not even a shade is visible to me.

Comment: Sorry then, but I can't help you as I can not reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem om my computer.
The problem is due to the fact that FMX does not paint some controls (e.g. Listbox misses right border) correctly when your Windows scaling isn't configured at 100%.
It probably depends on your screen resolution as well.
Try 100%, 125% or 150% scaling and observe if there are any differences.

Comment: It indeed works as it should be on 100% but damn since i have quite the bad eyesight i'm perma-using the 125% one. Now I'm now wondering how they could let such an obvious/enormous bug go and not fix it over years. I mean, almost everyone i know uses 125% or so for comfort.